# General topology: Showing a set is open.

Tags: general-topology

I am using Munkres and the problem states, let $\textbf{X}$ be a topological space: let $\textbf{A}$ be a subset of $\textbf{X}$. Suppose that for each $x \in \textbf{A}$ there is n open set $\textbf{U}$ containing x such that $\textbf{U}$ $\subset$ $\textbf{A}$. Show that $\textbf{A}$ is ppen in $\text{X}$.

Proof: Let $B$ be a basis for the topology $T$
on X. Define $A=\cup_{\alpha \in J} A_{\alpha}$. Given $x\in A$ there is an index $\alpha$ such that $x\in A_\alpha$. Since $A_\alpha$ is open, there exists a basis element $b'$ such that $x\in b' \subset A_\alpha$. Then $x\in b'$ and $b'  \subset A$, so $A$ is open by definition.

Am I doing this correctly? This is my first attempt at a proof in topology.

Comment: @Brad, I made an indexed family {$A_\alpha$} for $\alpha \in J $ of elements of our topology $T$ on $\textbf{X}$.

Comment: The only subsets that can be written as a union of such a family are the open sets (which are themselves, of course, elements of the topology). By writing $A$ as such a union, you are implicitly assuming that it is open -- which is the thing you're trying to prove.

Comment: if A is in a topological space which we have, then it must be open right?

Comment: No, not every subset of $\textbf X$ is an open set, but, by the very definition of open set, only those containted in the topology.  (I think you need to make sure you understand the difference between topology and topological space)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler proof would be to note that $A = \bigcup_{x \in A}\{x\} \subset \bigcup_{x \in A} \textbf U_x \subset A$, which implies $A = \bigcup_{x \in A} \textbf U_x$. Hence $A$ is open because it is the union of open sets.

Comment: here U is a subset of our topology right?

Comment: By $U_x$ I mean the open set containing $x$ and contained in $A$ (which exists by hyphotesis for every $x \in A$)

Comment: d***, how did I miss that.wow this makes so much sense now, I jjust reaad this question  over. thanks a ot